# How to get client_identification_sequence in QuickBlox for curl in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, quickblox

I am using Quickblox to send push notification from server. I want to get push token and create subscription from PHP. In my project I can send different parameters from ios to PHP script. But I cannot find out how to get value for client_identification_sequence in ios.

What actually this "client_identification_sequence" means?
How to get it for ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this guide how to work with iOS push notifications

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Did Register for Remote Notifications with Device Token (%@)", deviceToken);
}
```

**deviceToken** is the **client_identification_sequence** in general